FOMO and disillusionment with research
I have a been a physicist my whole life, doing a master and a PhD. I have specialised in quantum information, and I have published some good papers. I could take a shot at a career in academia, even if I could have done better probably during the PhD. However, I feel that research in quantum physics nowadays is not relevant at all. What drove me to physics was the possibility of working on relevant problems for current technologies, but I feel that today only ML is under the spotlight, and that research in physics is confined to academia only, at least regarding what a theoretician can do. This is the point where FOMO (fear of missing out comes into play). I feel that staying on this route of doing research in physics would alienate me more and more from reality, hurting my long term career opportunities and possibilities later life. In a sense I feel betrayed by my beloved subject, that I thought would leave me a lot of open doors, but in reality doesn't.
On the other end leaving research means stop publishing, and I feel that while I am still young I should have nurture my public image as an independent thinker in some field, even if this is not 100% aligned with current market needs. In other words, once you go to industry you become anonymous, and you are fighting an uphill battle for visibility.
The only thing that is restraining me from staying in research is fear, fear that the most I stay in academia the more it becomes difficult to find a job in industry, and if and when I fail as academic I will be left in the dust. Because of this I am losing passion for research. Though I like doing good work, research feels like such a solitary endeavour, and I worry I might not be cut out for it. I used to like studying with colleagues at the university, precisely because of the group dynamics, which I have completely lost in research.
How do you cope with the feeling that no one outside of your circles appreciates your work (i.e. would give you a job), and with the feeling of irrelevance of your discipline? When I studied physics at the university I couldn't imagine having to deal with this emotionally, beside the general bad employment conditions of postdocs.

I don't know if this is a helpful answer, but there's no shortage of jobs for ex-theoretical physicists, at least in America. I know a whole bunch who quit this year, and there isn't a single one who isn't making at least $500k a year now. AI and finance function as perfect safety nets.

Look - if you go into finance or ML, all you're going to end up doing is helping a bunch of billionaires put more people out of work (by developing technology that will replace them).  At least doing physics you won't do any harm and might even stumble upon some beautiful stuff.

It's a bit surprising to see this perspective from someone specialized in quantum information, which remains very relevant and with opportunities for theory work, both in academic and industrial research.

Seek professional counseling. Looking for helpful hints here probably is not a bad idea, but you need to look at the fuller context of where you are in life, how you got there, what you now value, and your next steps. Good luck!

@AlexanderWoo: I want to push back on your assertion that "going into ML will help a bunch of billionaires put more people out of work". I am a math Ph.D. and have been doing ML since it used to be called "statistics". I forecast demand at supermarkets, reducing spoilage and stockouts (and would argue that this makes the world a better place). Employees at our customers actually love having this tedious part of their job automated so they have more time to do stuff that actually adds value. I would gently request you be a little more nuanced. There are good uses of ML out there. Thank you!

I think it's important for you to realise that FOMO is an irrational fear of missing out. Whatever you choose to do, there will be other things that you could also do that also have a chance to blow up and be the thing to do for a few years. Imagine working in the early days of computing - back then, it would be easy to get swept up in the massive strides that, for example, medicine made in comparison to the rather "niche" and academic topic of computation, and decide you are wasting your time. In retrospect you would not view it like that, of course.

I believe you should work on what you care about and are good at. If that happens to be generative AI - good for you, right now is a golden age. In all likelihood it won't stay that way forever.

"I feel that while I am still young I should have nurture my public image as an independent thinker in some field" – Your "public image" with whom exactly?

"Fear that the more I stay in academia the more it becomes difficult to find a job in industry" -- this is true, but equally this would be true for any profession of choice. "I fear that the more I stay in basket weaving, it becomes more difficult to get a job in bird cataloguing. This is true even for professions more related than in my fictional example - the more you get experience in X, the more difficult you make it to obtain an offer for jobs outside of X, and the more effort you'll have to put in to convince the interviewers that your skills are transferable.

I want to push back hard against the idea that academic scientists are more publicly known than industry scientists. The expected amount of fame is essentially zero in both cases--even if you have successful career!

Answering to Adam, who posed the question "Your "public image" with whom exactly?". In research you have the possibility to publish, develop open source projects of various kind. The answer to your question is to the whole world, and yes also to possible employer. As someone noticed doing technical work is not a good way to be famous, but the point is not to be famous, it is to prove to have a track record of successfully solving hard and useful problems in a field. If you work for a corporation you would have to convince the next corporation that you are actually good at something.

I'm trying to stay fairly general here so that this answer has a chance to fit within our guidelines. In short: All of the concerns that you have are concerns that you can mitigate along an academic career track with more or less effort. But the mitigation can take more or less effort. The characteristic of tenure-track research jobs are that they require juggling many different types of tasks for relatively low pay. Supply in the labor market is relatively high compared to demand. At some point you must choose your priorities and appetite for certain types of risk in order to decide on a career path.

On the other end leaving research means stop publishing, and I feel that while I am still young I should have nurture my public image as an independent thinker in some field, even if this is not 100% aligned with current market needs. In other words, once you go to industry you become anonymous, and you are fighting an uphill battle for visibility. [...] How [d]o you cope with the feeling that no one outside of your circles appreciates your work (i.e. would give you a job), and with the feeling of irrelevance of your discipline[?]

This goes for practically everyone and every type of job all the time. As far as science is concerned, progress is the work of a great many hands. Physicists who are nobodies in an absolute sense round up to 100%. Almost any individual study a researcher conducts is locally irrelevant, but it does add up.
For most academic subjects, you're going to have to be intrinsically motivated about the work that you do...find it fun or interesting or relevant in its own right. That's because the extrinsic interest from the general public in most subjects is low. By the way, "external" appreciation waxes and wanes over time, independent of the quality of work being done. Today "AI" is hot (machine learning is so last year). Tomorrow, something else.
If you're looking for fame, even limited fame, technical work of most sorts is largely not a smart strategy to achieve that.
Furthermore, you will almost certainly be anonymous no matter what you do with your life. If that bothers you to the point that you'd like to prioritize fame in your career decisions, you need to do that very proactively.

I feel that staying on this route of doing research in physics would alienate me more and more from reality, hurting my long term career opportunities and possibilities later life.

This certainly can happen. If you're strategic about the work and skills you develop in your research portfolio, however, you can mitigate a substantial amount of the risk of over-skilling in academia only to realize you want to pivot to something else later. Spend some of your time coauthoring on ML papers or similar, if that's your alternative route.

Your degrees have provided you with transferable skills. If you do not see your skills as transferable then you will struggle in both academia and industry. If your plan was to continue your PhD work as an independent then you are setting yourself up to be left in the dust.
If you feel your research is irrelevant, then you must find something you deem relevant.
If you want to be a successful researcher you have to be creative and ready to pivot by leveraging your skill set and picking up new skills along the way.
If you struggle working alone, then find collaborators.
All of your problems have solutions that require just a bit of effort on your end.

Please cheer up. These days, experts on quantum physics, especially on quantum information, are needed by large and small companies working on a broad range of topics related to Quantum Computer — from hardware design to the underlying physics to algorithm development.
Off the top of my head, this startup is looking for quantum physicists like you, who are open to expanding their expertise into algorithms.  I heard through word of mouth that, while they received plenty of applications in the US, they’ve had a harder time finding the right people in the UK.  Want to give it a shot?
Aside from small startups like this one, major companies such as Microsoft, IBM, Google, and even some banks are now establishing research groups focused on quantum computing. Someone with your skills could definitely be of interest to them.
Your position in the market may be stronger than you think. I wish you luck in your quest!


I feel that staying on this route of doing research in physics would alienate me more and more from reality, hurting my long term career opportunities and possibilities later life. In a sense I feel betrayed by my beloved subject, that I thought would leave me a lot of open doors, but in reality doesn't.

I studied civil engineering and my first job right after my undergrad was in programming which I learned on my own -- it had no connection to my degree. I then quit my job and started a PhD because research was always my dream. One might think that I "wasted" 1.5 year working in industry when I could have been already working in research. But it actually was psychologically very beneficial for me throughout my PhD because it gave me confidence that I can get a well-paid job outside of the academic context if I ever wanted to. And it is possible because our skills as academics are generally sought by industries. If you know programming, if you're a creative thinker and a good problem-solver, if you've overcame obstacles and completed long projects, if you're a good colleague and can teach your teammates things when they ask you for help, then you can do well in an industry job. Reasonable people recruiting you will realize that and will appreciate your skills. (Unreasonable people won't but then you also wouldn't like to work for such people, right?)

The only thing that is restraining me from staying in research is fear, fear that the most I stay in academia the more it becomes difficult to find a job in industry, and if and when I fail as academic I will be left in the dust.

Perhaps it's only when you haven't had that prior experience with industry that you worry that no one might ever want to hire you. And that's understandable because you simply don't know what the other side is like. FWIW, your fear may never come true if it comes to this that you start looking for an industry job. So you might as well relax and do research that you like for as long as you can :)

Though I like doing good work, research feels like such a solitary endeavour, and I worry I might not be cut out for it. I used to like studying with colleagues at the university, precisely because of the group dynamics, which I have completely lost in research.

I completely get you. The isolation is tough. Especially if you live abroad and have no friends and family around. I'd recommend trying to see (perhaps with a therapist) if your sense of isolation might currently be the main reason why you see other aspects of your work as unmotivating and passionless. I know I easily begin to feel discouraged when I cross a certain threshold of isolation in research. I just started a postdoc this year and I feel much more left on my own compared to my PhD. This can really crush my motivation at times. It's good to have a network of old colleagues and build a network of new colleagues that you can reach out to every once in a while. Either create new projects for collaborations with them or just ask them to brainstorm ideas with you so that research starts to feel more social and fun again.
I haven't really found other solution then this: Whenever I start to feel depressed due to isolation, I now know that only I can take initiative to get me out of this. I then take active steps to reach out to people. I just outright ask them if they can talk about an idea with me or if they can meet to give me advice on something. I've even been reaching to people I didn't know before whose research I admire and, interestingly, the vast majority of time they are happy to meet with me! (Perhaps they feel as isolated and craving human contact as me?)
I also know that regular contact with other researchers, especially my PhD mentors who know me well and care for me, helps me to regulate my general anxiety about the future, so that's something that could help you reduce your fears as well. Somehow, work becomes just a bit less intense and stressful after a nice catching-up with them...
Wishing you all the best!
